# Trouble with static linking a python module

Tags: python, c++, gcc

I'm using SWIG to package some C++ into a python module. I'm trying to get this to build with statically-linked libraries so it can be deployed to a system with an older glibc / libc++ / etc. I can get libgcc and libstdc++ to static link but I can't figure out a way to static link against glibc. Google solutions seem to be either static linking a whole executable or telling me not to do it...

Anyways, here's the important bits of my `setup.py`

```
cargs = ['-O3','-fPIC','-std=c++11']
largs = ['-lgsl','-lgslcblas','-static-libgcc','-static-libstdc++','-Bstatic -lc']

StopPow_module = Extension('_StopPow',
                        sources=['StopPow_wrap.cxx', '../src/StopPow.cpp', '../src/StopPow_Plasma.cpp', '../src/StopPow_PartialIoniz.cpp','../src/StopPow_SRIM.cpp', '../src/StopPow_BetheBloch.cpp', '../src/StopPow_LP.cpp', '../src/StopPow_AZ.cpp','../src/StopPow_Mehlhorn.cpp','../src/StopPow_Grabowski.cpp','../src/StopPow_Zimmerman.cpp','../src/StopPow_BPS.cpp','../src/AtomicData.cpp','../src/PlotGen.cpp', '../src/Spectrum.cpp'],
                        extra_compile_args = cargs,
                        extra_link_args = largs,
                        language="c++" )

setup (name = 'StopPow',
   version = '0.2',
   description = """Stopping power library""",
   ext_modules = [StopPow_module],
   py_modules = ["StopPow","StopPow_Plasma","StopPow_PartialIoniz","StopPow_SRIM","StopPow_BetheBloch","StopPow_LP","StopPow_AZ","StopPow_Mehlhorn","StopPow_Grabowski","StopPow_Zimmerman","StopPow_BPS","AtomicData","PlotGen","Spectrum"],
   )
```

Which builds OK but still needs libc (among a few others):

```
ldd _StopPow.cpython-33m.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff309fe000)
    libgsl.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgsl.so.0 (0x00007f99e8c0b000)
    libgslcblas.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgslcblas.so.0 (0x00007f99e89bf000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f99e86ba000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f99e849d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f99e80d5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f99e941c000)
```

libgsl is okay but how can I get it to statically link against the others?

Comment: You probably need to pass just `-static` to get static glibc.